# fread_s reading the wrong amount of bytes

Tags: c++, file, runtime-error, eof, unexpectendoffile

I am reading a collection file (20 or so small files in one) with `fread_s` and the content is being written in a `struct`. Like **99%** of the times it reads the data correctly, but one time, at always the same position it seems to ignore the byte size of the element size parameter and just reads 500 or so bytes until it aborts and reports a `feof` error. The thing is, it doesn't even write the last three bytes of the int to the struct.

When I remove the checks, and let it continue reading, it will read normal again, like nothing happened.

I observed that the `_Placeholder` variable in the file pointer gets changed to a different value, and then back again, but I guess its just the `eof` error getting packed in there.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct fileHeader {
    __int32 typeID;
    bool isGFX;
    char filename[8];
    __int32 offset;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#define HEADERSIZE 68
#define FILEHEADERSIZE 17

....
FILE *file;
fopen_s(&file, filename.c_str(), "r");

for (int i = 0; i < header.files - 1; i++) {
    fseek(file, HEADERSIZE + i * FILEHEADERSIZE, 0);

    fileHeader headerFile;
    memset(&headerFile, 0, FILEHEADERSIZE);

    int oldPointer = ftell(file); //118
    int d = fread_s(&headerFile, FILEHEADERSIZE, FILEHEADERSIZE, 1, file); //returns 0
    int newPointer = ftell(file); //630

    int e = errno; //0
    int ea = ferror(file); //0
    int ef = feof(file); //1

    //getting used here in a function
}
headerFile = {typeID=17 isGFX=true filename=0x00fefd05 "CURSORR" offset = 164} - offset should be 6820
```

Comment: So how do you open the file ?

Comment: with `fopen_s(&file, filename.c_str(), "r");`

Comment: If you're on Windows, do you need to use `"rb"` as the open mode, to avoid problems if one of the bytes in the numbers in the file header happens to be 0x1A, aka control-Z?

Comment: 'Tis interesting: the [`fread_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread-s) function appears in neither TR 24731-1 nor in Annex K of C11.  It seems to be a Microsoft-only function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jonathan Leffler said in the comments, the mistake was, that I didn't read in binary mode. a simple change `fopen_s(&file, filename.c_str(), "r");` to `fopen_s(&file, filename.c_str(), "rb");` fixed the problem.